# $injector:modulerr Error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

So I'm attempting to learn Angular using a MEAN stack and I'm having an issue getting a simple app that I'm playing around with working again.

The specific error i'm getting right now is `angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]` and after hours of researching, troubleshooting, and banging my head I can't seem to get my app working again. It worked at one point with a very basic app.js but I've since changed it use an anonymous function and adjusted my controller.js and factory.js.

Here's the code for my app.js, factory.js, and controller.js

If anyone would be willing to assist me in locating what the issue is I'd greatly appreciate it!

app.js

```
(function(){
var iquueApp = angular.module('iquueApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'iquueApp.iquueCtrl', 'iquueApp.iquueFactory'])
  .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/partials/property-dashboard.html',
    controller: 'iquueCtrl'
}).when('/admin', {
    templateUrl: '/partials/admin-dashboard.html',
    controller: 'iquueCtrl'
}).when('/admin/property-setup', {
    templateUrl: '/partials/admin-prop-setup.html',
    controller: 'iquueCtrl'
}).when('/login', {
    templateUrl: '/auth/login/login.html',
    controller: 'iquueCtrl'
})
.when('/register', {
    templateUrl: '/auth/register/register.view.html',
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });

  // use the HTML5 History API
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

})();
```

factory.js

```
angular.module('iquueApp.iquueFactory',[])
.factory('iquueFactory', function($http) {
  var urlBase = '/api/hubs';
  var _iquueService = {};

  _iquueService.getHub = function() {
    return $http.get(urlBase);
  };

  _iquueService.saveHub = function(secretKey) {
    return $http.post(urlBase, secretKey);
  };

  _iquueService.updateHub = function(secretKey) {
    return $http.put(urlBase, secretKey);
  };

  _iquueService.deleteHub = function(id) {
    return $http.delete(urlBase + '/' + id);
  };

  return _iquueService;
});
```

controller.js

```
/Angular Controllers
angular.module('iquueApp.iquueCtrl',[])
.controller('iquueCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope, iquueFactory) {

  $scope.hubs = [];
  $scope.isEditable = [];

  // get all hubs on Load
  iquueFactory.getHub().then(function(data) {
    $scope.hubs = data.data;
  });

});
```

Comment: Post the exact error as @sireken stated. He should have posted that as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments guys. This error was due to not loading angular-resource.js correctly. I resolved it shortly after posting this question.

Answer (score -2):

what is the exact error? try to post the exact error as seen in the console.  This will tell you what module or controller is causing the error..

like this one... here MyApp is where the error is...

```
Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$injector/unpr?p0=e
at Error (native)
at     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:6:417
at      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:38:307
at d     (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:36:308)
at Object.e [as invoke]     (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:37:64)
at d     (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:35:301)
at     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:35:425
at s     (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:7:302)
at g     (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:35:202)
at Ob     (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js:38:435
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for responding. I actually just figured it out. Turns out this error was being caused by the JS not being loaded correctly on my end. I was missing the angular-resource.min.js file due to a typo. 

I also didn't get a detailed error but I'm thinking that this was due to me using the minified version of angular?

Hopefully this post will help someone else who comes across this issue!